# How to have javascript and python communicate together in a phone application?

Tags: javascript, python, react-native

**How to have java script and python communicate together in a phone application?**

I am working on this phone app as a project of mine. I have a python script which web scrapes data from other websites. I am trying to have include this data in my app. I need a way to use python in react-native so I can connect it with java script. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Maybe react has any type of library to do that in a more easy way, but you can do that with sockets, files, or databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) to create one connection between Python and JavaScript, or use [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/home) to transcript your Python code into JavaScript.

I also had this doubt but the solution that I found was to use AWS lambda to run my Python code, but in this case, my app already has the necessity to connect with my API, so it was one simple and smart solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

See. In a few words, what you would do is:

1. Gather/Scrape the data.
2. Insert data into database of your choice using a server side language of your choice.
   2.1. This is generally done by creating something called an API.
3. You then query this API using an HTTP/S React Native library that is hopefully available.
4. Once that data is properly stored in the database, you can run all kinds of reports on it.

Comment: I get your solution, but it doesn't apply to my situation. I need communication of python and javascript both ways. Javascript enters the data which needs to be scraped, and then python outputs the resulting data. Also, I webscrape the data live, meaning it is different for every user and is not just in the morning.